# Getting airline's past-positive covid form signed by GP

Tags: uk, covid-19, australia, qantas

This is a reach of desperation.

My wife and daughter are are in the UK (I am at home in Australia) and had a positive PCR test more than 2 weeks ago. They are vaccinated, have no symptoms and have quarantined accordingly.

Qantas requires them to have a GP sign a form, explained [here](https://www.qantas.com/au/en/coronavirus/vaccination-exemptions-medical-clearance.html#past-positive-clearance), stating the above.

The problem she is having is that every single GP she has called has said that they won't sign it. After speaking to Qantas they say they are getting a lot of people who are able to get the form signed. We really need to know where they are going to get this done so that my wife can bring our 2yo daughter home.

Comment: This is just an idea, but perhaps try GPs who lean towards the "natural remedies" style of treatment. Even if it's not the type of GP you might normally choose, the key thing you need at this point is a signature.

Comment: Not sure how many weeks it's been since the positive test, but if it's been a while, they may start to reach the point where there's a semi-decent chance they'll test PCR negative (of course, some people do test PCR+ for months). If a new test is easier to get than finding a doctor willing to sign the form, it might be worth trying while they look for a doctor.

Comment: Thanks @GregHewgill, I've passed that info on to her.

It's only been a little over 2 weeks. She will keep doing PCR tests just in case but I know the chances are that they will be PCR+ for a while yet

Comment: Im the husband of a ex-UK GP, and there is no way a British GP is going to take on the liability of you flying just because Qantas want them to - thats what the form is about, and thats why GPs are refusing to sign them.  More and more activities are requiring GP “approval”, and there have been several GPs who have subsequently been sued after something happened to a person after they signed the form saying they could go sky diving/bungee jumping/whatever.  GPs just cant take on the liability, so they refuse to sign the forms now.

Comment: @Moo I appreciate this. However, the form is not saying that the person is fit to fly, it is just stating that the person has had a positive PCR >14 days ago and is no longer showing symptoms. They are not declaring that this person is not going to contract the virus nor that the GP is responsible for the person doing so once the form is signed. In this regard the form is a complete waste of paper as far as compliance is concerned but, nevertheless, is a requirement to enter Australia. According to Qantas, thousands of these are being received per week. I just can't find out where from

Comment: @Wildcard27 its still getting the GP to sign their name to something that they cannot accept liability for - especially the “no longer showing symptoms” part, for example (plenty of ways for that to backfire on the GP).  Qantas is trying to shift their liability here, the GPs wont accept it for them.

Comment: @Moo again, this isn't just a Qantas requirement, it's an Aus Gov requirement (https://www.health.gov.au/health-alerts/covid-19/international-travel/inbound). Trust me, Qantas would prefer that there are no forms that required signing; they are hanging on by a thread and need people on planes. Many others are somehow managing to adhere to these requirements, I just need to know how. And, like I say, the for does not put liability on the GP. If a GP doesn't know when a patient is showing Covid symptoms, then I expect they wouldn't be a GP for very long during a pandemic...

Comment: @Wildcard27 yes it *does* put liability on the GP - there is utterly no other reason to have a GP sign it if it doesnt shift liability.  The GP signs it, the patient has a lingering condition not detected, and thats the GP in hot water with the GMC after the complaint is made. Believe me, this is being discussed in GP circles and no one is happy with being presented to sign someone off as fit and healthy to do X.  I dont know who is presenting Qantas with signed forms, but you are going to struggle to find a GP to sign it - your best bet is probably going private, which will cost you.

Comment: @Wildcard27 as for your comment about “ If a GP doesn't know when a patient is showing Covid symptoms, then I expect they wouldn't be a GP for very long during a pandemic”, its simple - GPs are overworked, understaffed and get to see you for 8 minutes during which time you can lie your freaking ass off to get on that plane.  You really think they can do a massive battery of tests to ensure you arent asymptomatic or suffering a low-impact infection before signing that form?  *Thats* what Im talking about, and *thats* why GPs hate these forms - for you its a tick box exercise, for them its more.

Comment: Have you tried a private GP? They might be willing to sign if she pays their consultation fee. It might be cheaper than a PCR test.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions regarding a private clinic. This seems to be the way to go. Fingers crossed. @Moo I meant no disrespect and I in no way envy the stress and pressure that the doctors are all under currently and things like this don't do anything but add to that pressure. As mentioned, I just want my daughter back in my arms. Nothing is more important to me right now and this anxiety means I may come across as arrogant. I don't intend to and I apologise if I offended any one here by my tone. I appreciate all your comments.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.